# getResources, get the latest resource per container

Tags: modx-revolution, getresource

Using getResources, i want to get the latest resource created per container, so here's the resource tree structure:

```
-Parent
  --Container 1
     ---Resource 1
     ---Resource 2
     ---Latest Resource
  --Container 2
     ---Resource 1
     ---Latest Resource
  --Container 3
     ---Resource 1
     ---Resource 2
     ---Latest Resource
```

By using `[[getResources]]` how can i possibly be able to get only the resources `Latest Resource`?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want listed, is it something like: 
- Container 1 Latest Resource
- Container 2 Latest Resource
- Container 3 Latest Resource
? How is "Latest Resource" determined... by the most recent to be added, published, updated, etc?

Comment: Can you just use a getResource per container? Or are they dynamically created containers? You could then sort by the publish date of the resource, eg: &sortby=`{"publishedon":"ASC"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
&parents=`1`&sortBy=`publishedOn`&sortdir=`DESC`&limit=`1`
&parents=`2`&sortBy=`publishedOn`&sortdir=`DESC`&limit=`1`
&parents=`3`&sortBy=`publishedOn`&sortdir=`DESC`&limit=`1`
```

You could also do a getPage with a custom Snippet grabbing the last modResource of the desired parents.
The parents=...  above will have to represent actual modResource IDs available in the Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a nested getResources-call.

Assuming that all Containters have the same template (e.g. "3"):

1. getResources

   ```
   [[getResources? 
          &limit=`0`
          &depth=`1`
          &where=`{"template:=":3}`
          &includeContent=`0`
          &includeTVs=`0`
          &processTVs=`0`
          &tpl=`chunk1`
   ]]
   ```
2. chunk1

   ```
   [[getResources?
           &parents=`[[+id]]`
           &sortby=`{"publishedon":"DESC"}`
           &hideContainers=`1`
           &limit=`1`
           &depth=`1`
           &includeContent=`1` 
           &includeTVs=`1` 
           &processTVs=`1`
           &tpl=`chunk2`
   ]]
   ```
3. chunk2

   Here you put the placeholdes you want, e.g. `[[+pagetitle]]`, `[[+content]]`